# Jenkins keeps running the old Protractor test scripts

Tags: jenkins, protractor

I set up Jenkins Pipeline to execute protractor tests. The project is currently running from my local drive and I am running them using the following commands:

```
npm install
npm start
```

When I set up my projects, the first time (v1.0) it runs fine. but if I update my test scripts to (v 2.0) and rebuild it, Jenkins still executes the old codes (V 1.0).

One thing I need to highlight.. When I install Jenkins, it does not create the home folder C:/users//.jenkins.. on my local drive. I am using Windows 10 and the Jenkins Version is 2.150.1 .

How can I overcome this and make Jenkins to run the updated scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, you need to enter your project root folder every time.

```
cd <project root folder where the package.json besides>
npm install
npm start
```